# document.getElementById returns null

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, button, null

I'm trying to write an extension for Chrome at the moment.

What I'm trying to do right now is create an HTML form that has a button on it which, when pressed, shows a message box.

My project consists of an HTML file and a JavaScript file.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  width:100px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
</style>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="buttonid" type="button" value="try it"></input>
</body>



chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(onCreated());

function myFunction()
{
alert("Hello World!");
}

function onCreated()
{
    var fld = document.getElementById("buttonid");
    if(fld==null)
    {
        alert("null");
    }
    else
    {
        alert("not null");
    }   
}
```

So my understanding is, when the HTML is rendered it runs my onCreated() function. This then looks for an element with ID="buttonid". But it is ALWAYS returning null, so a message box comes up saying "null".

Can anyone explain this? This seems to make no sense. I have tried running a slightly adapted version in IE but with identical results.

Just to be clear, I know this won't fulfil my description above but I am trying to access the button from the JavaScript before I attach an event to it.

Answer (score 5):

Replace

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(onCreated());
```

with

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(onCreated);
```

Event handler rule #1: [No parentheses!](http://quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html#link2) - you do not want to execute the function, but register it.

Comment: Should the first line (invalid) still have a caused the null? 'onCreated' was still being called after the markup was rendered...

Comment: Thanks Bergi, but when I do that nothing happens at all which is even more of a problem! I am now not even getting a message box saying anything!

Comment: @flem: Really? I don't have any knowledge of chrome extensions, but it was the first obvious bug that I saw. Assuming the posted code is the `popup.js` script, the button would be added to DOM after the scripts execution.

Comment: @Bergi. I'm referring to just JS in general. My assumption would have been that `chrome.tabs.onCreated...` is fired when a new tab is launched. If true, this would trigger before any content is rendered.

Comment: @MattHollands: Did you [open a tab](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#event-onCreated)? I'm not sure what you actually want to do

Comment: Hmmm, yes that's a fair point. I have not got much experience with HTML etc, I'm more used to C etc. What could I use instead to imply that I want onCreated() to run when the HTML is rendered?

Comment: @Matt: Try simple [`document.onDOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/DOMContentLoaded_(event))

Comment: @MattHollands. Given the position of the JS (right after the HTML), just a simple call to `onCreated`.

Comment: @Bergi I replace the "chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener(onCreated);" with "document.onDOMContentLoaded.addListener(onCreated);" But still nothing...

Comment: I made a fiddle of this exact code, and it works as expected.  I just wrapped a script tag around the script.  And I put an onclick event on the button to trigger the onCreated function [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bfelda/HcdqH/)

Comment: @flem Although I think that would work, Chrome extensions don't allow inline code so it has to be done from inside the JS. But thanks :)

Comment: @BenFelda Thanks for your post. Unfortunately Chrome extensions cannot use inline code so I cannot call onCreated from inside the HTML

Answer (score 0):

Fixed! I placed window.onload=function(){onCreated()}; on the first line. This means that when the html is loaded it runs my function "onCreated"... Thanks guys, you pushed me in the right direction.